# The function users_list() from rocketchat_API returns 'error-invalid-query'

Tags: python, rocket.chat

The following code has worked for several weeks:

```
from pprint import pprint
from rocketchat_API.rocketchat import RocketChat

username = "bot"
password = "password"
server_url = "https://server.com/"
bot = RocketChat(username, password, server_url=server_url)

pprint(bot.users_list().json())
```

I always got a list of users:

```
{'count': 10,
 'offset': 0,
 'success': True,
 'total': 10,
 'users': [{'_id': '123456789',
            'active': True,
            'emails': [{'address': 'test@mail.com',
                        'verified': False}],
            'lastLogin': '2022-06-23T17:00:32.368Z',
            'name': 'TestUser',
            'nameInsensitive': 'testuser',
            'roles': ['user'],
            'status': 'offline',
            'username': 'TUser'},
            ...
          ]
}
```

But now i get the return:

```
{'error': 'Invalid attribute: emails.address [error-invalid-query]',
 'errorType': 'error-invalid-query',
 'success': False}
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with the authentication. Can you cross-check the username and password

Comment: @peerpressure username and password are correct. It looks like permissions are missing as it works with an admin account.